# How to show an image right next a text when hovering over it? The position of the image would have to change according to the length of the text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make different images appear over different link sizes when the mouse is hovering over the links. Just like in [this page](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/archetype/standard-dimir-control-eld#paper). Note that the images appear right next to the links without overlapping them. Is there a way to do this automatically or is it necessary to configure link by link?
So far, i was only able to make this:

```css
.popup {
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.popup span {
    position:fixed;
    top:170px;
    width:350px;
    left:-999em;      
}
.popup:hover {visibility:visible}
.popup:hover span {left:800px;}
* html .popup span {position:absolute;}
```

```html
<p><a class="popup" href="#">Ship 1<span><img src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/e/5/e5dfd9fe-40d1-4902-a782-7dc18e72fcc4.jpg?1602129817"></span></a> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it using `display` but also `position: absolute` to be sure to not break the page structure:

### DEMO with image out of `a` link (same effect as your link):

```css
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
}
.popup {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.popup + .popover-img {
  position: relative;
}
.popup + .popover-img img {
  display:none;
}

.popup:hover + .popover-img img {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<p class="d-flex">
  <a class="popup" href="#">Ship 1</a>
  <a class="popover-img" href="#">
    <img src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/e/5/e5dfd9fe-40d1-4902-a782-7dc18e72fcc4.jpg?1602129817">
  </a>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</p>
```

### DEMO with image in `a` link

```css
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
}
.popup {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.popup .popover-img {
  position: relative;
}
.popup .popover-img img {
  display:none;
}

.popup:hover .popover-img img {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="d-flex">
  <a class="popup" href="#">Ship 1 <span class="popover-img" href="#">
    <img src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/e/5/e5dfd9fe-40d1-4902-a782-7dc18e72fcc4.jpg?1602129817">
  </span></a>
  
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the image inside the anchor. Move it outside, right beside the link with no space. I think it should work fine like that. Remove the span if you don't need it.

```
<p>
    <a class="popup" href="#">Ship 1</a><img src="https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/e/5/e5dfd9fe-40d1-4902-a782-7dc18e72fcc4.jpg?1602129817"> 
</p>
```

Note: this should solve the positioning problem but not showing (popping up) the image, which should be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.popup {
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.popup span {
    position: relative;     
}
.popup span img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
}
.popup:hover {visibility:visible}
.popup:hover span img {display: block}
```

Just make the image display block on hovering in the popup

Comment: Your solution also solved my problem. Thank you very much!